# Las siguientes secciones se han definido, pero no se han presentado para la página de diseño "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy creando un formulario con la utilizacion de DropDownList con la requiero la implementacion de un scripts pero me arroja el error Las siguientes secciones se han definido, pero no se han presentado para la página de diseño "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts". supongo que mencionado error es porque en la vista lo inclui pero aun estoy aprendiendo y no he podido encontrar solucion dejo el codigo de la vista

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/general.css" />
@model ProyectoDicar.Models.municipio
<div id="reg" style="margin:100px">
<h2 style="font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', 
 sans-serif; color:azure"> Area de Operaciones</h2>
<hr />
<div style="position:center; align-content:center; align-items:center; 
 justify-content:center">

        <input id="texB3" type="number" placeholder="Sección" />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdDepart, new { @class = "control- 
        label col-md-2" })

        @Html.DropDownList("IdDepart")


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdMuni, new { @class = "control-label 
         col-md-2" })

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdMuni, new 
        List<SelectListItem> {
                                                             new 
        SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" }})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdMuni)


    </span>

 </div>
 </div>
 @section Scripts{
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#IdDepart").change(function () {
            //Se limpia el contenido del dropdownlist
            $("#IdMuni").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                //Llamado al metodo en el controlador
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStateByIdDepart", "municipio")',
                dataType: 'json',
                //Parametros que se envian al metodo del controlador
                data: { IdDepart: $("#IdDepart").val() },
                //En caso de resultado exitoso
                success: function (municipio) {
                    if (municipio.length == 0) {
                        $("#IdMuni").append('<option value=""></option>');
                    }
                    else {
                        //Se agrega el elemento vacio para poder desplegar 
    que seleccione una opcion
                        $("#IdMuni").append('<option value=""></option>');
                        $.each(municipio, function (i, municipio) {
                            $("#IdMuni").append('<option value="' + 
  municipio.Value + '">' +
                                municipio.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                    //Recargar el plugin para que tenga la funcionalidad del 
   componente
                    $("#IdMuni").select2({ placeholder: "Select One State", 
  width: "20%" });
                 },
                //Mensaje de error en caso de fallo
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
        //Se agrega el elemento vacio para poder desplegar que seleccione 
   una opcion
        $("#IdMuni").select2({ placeholder: "Select One State", width: "20%" 
   });
        //Se agrega el elemento vacio para poder desplegar que seleccione 
   una opción
        $("#IdDepart").select2({ placeholder: "Select One Country", width: 
  "20%" });
    });
   </script>
  }
```

Agradezco su colaboracion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu `_Layout.cshtml` verifica que tengas `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` en la parte inferior o donde necesitas hacer el llamado de tus scripts. Con `false` indicas que esa sección no es requerida para todas las vistas.